# Websockets over HTTPS with spring boot 1.0.0.RC5 and tomcat 8.0.3

Tags: spring, security, websocket, spring-boot, stomp

I have a working example of the web socket (ws) non secure implementation application using spring boot 1.0.0.RC5 and tomcat 8.0.3.
Now i would like to switch to wss i.e. using my own self signed certificate that had been loaded by tomcat already.

This question has two parts one theoretical and one practical:

Theoretical => Do i need to have tomcat listening on two ports? i.e. on http and https. The reason i am asking this is because i read that during a web socket communication the first part of the connection is made over http and then there is so called "upgrade" to websockets. I am posting example of my test

```
GET /hello HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.5:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en,en-gb;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Sec-WebSocket-Key: wIKSOMgaHbEmkaRuEHZ6IA==
Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket


HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: 8trj6dyzlYdDUA3nAuwiM7SijRM=
Date: Mon, 31 Mar 2014 10:29:19 GMT


..,O.do..*i..nM,..\;..I=.
C!.U.~.U....I....-..Xu.T...H...T.E.d
.'
CONNECTED
heart-beat:0,0
version:1.1

.
.....]..M...F...f9..z?...9..{4..{4..5r...4..h/..{4..|W..
```

How this communication would look like over wss? Do we have the "upgrade" part as well, if so in this case we need http in order for that construct to work.

Practical => The problem i am facing is that the part of the code that is responsible for creating the stomp message is not working i.e. when i open the page

```
https://127.0.0.5:8888/wsTest
```

firefox tels me
"This Connection is Untrusted" then i tell firefox "I understand the risk" and add the certificate as "Security Exception". From that point the certificate is stored under the firefox "servers" tab.
All good till now. However when i change to wss this game does not work as i expected it to work. i.e.  This is the function that is creating the socket on the client side.

```
     function connect() {
            var socket = new WebSocket("wss://127.0.0.5:8888/hello");

            stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
            stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
                setConnected(true);
                console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
                stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function(greeting){
                    showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
                });
            });
        }
```

if i change the line

```
var socket = new WebSocket("wss://127.0.0.5:8888/hello");
```

to the http version i.e.

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.5:8080/hello");
```

then all works again.  The problem seems to be with the line

```
stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
```

however according to this bug note (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11436) this should be the correct line

I have generated the ceritficate with the command:

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA  -keystore /home/tito/Projects/syncServer/Server/certificate/sync.keystore
```

The server side:

```
@Configuration
public class TomcatEmbeded extends SpringServletContainerInitializer {


    final int http_port = 8080;
    final int https_port = 8888;
    final String keystoreFile = "/home/tito/Projects/syncServer/Server/certificate/sync.keystore";
    final String keystorePass = "changeit";
    final String keystoreType = "JKS";
    final String keystoreProvider = "SUN";
    final String keystoreAlias = "tomcat";
    final String https_scheme = "https";
    final String http_scheme = "http";

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {


        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(http_port);

        factory.setTomcatContextCustomizers(
                Arrays.asList (
                        new TomcatContextCustomizer[]{ 
                                tomcatContextCustomizer() 
                                } 
                            )
                        );

        factory.addConnectorCustomizers( new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(Connector con) {
                    Http11NioProtocol proto = (Http11NioProtocol) con.getProtocolHandler();

                    try {

                        con.setPort(https_port);
                        con.setSecure(true);
                        con.setScheme("https");
                        con.setAttribute("keyAlias", keystoreAlias);
                        con.setAttribute("keystorePass", keystorePass.toString());
                        try {
                            con.setAttribute("keystoreFile", ResourceUtils.getFile(keystoreFile).getAbsolutePath());
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot load keystore", e);
                        }

                        con.setAttribute("clientAuth", "false");
                        con.setAttribute("sslProtocol", "TLS");
                        con.setAttribute("SSLEnabled", true);

                        proto.setSSLEnabled(true);
                        proto.setKeystoreFile(keystoreFile);
                        proto.setKeystorePass(keystorePass);
                        proto.setKeystoreType(keystoreType);
                        proto.setProperty("keystoreProvider", keystoreProvider.toString());
                        proto.setKeyAlias(keystoreAlias);

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("can't access keystore: [" + "keystore"
                                + "] or truststore: [" + "keystore" + "]", ex);
                    }
                    System.out.println("INIT HTTPS");

                }
            }
        );


        factory.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(httpConnector());
//      factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.404, "/notfound.html");
        System.out.println("TOMCAT CUSTOME SETTINGS INITILIZED");

        return factory;
    }


    private Connector httpConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector();
        connector.setScheme(this.http_scheme);
        connector.setSecure(true);
        connector.setPort(this.http_port);
        System.out.println("INIT port HTTP");
        return connector;
    }


    @Bean 
    public TomcatContextCustomizer tomcatContextCustomizer() {
        System.out.println("TOMCATCONTEXTCUSTOMIZER INITILIZED");
        return new TomcatContextCustomizer() {

            @Override
            public void customize(Context context) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                context.addServletContainerInitializer(new WsSci(), null);


            }
        };
    }
```

here is the web socket configuration portion

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/hello");
    }


    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration channelRegistration) {
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientOutboundChannel(ChannelRegistration channelRegistration) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> arg0) {

        return true;
    }
```

additional messages seen on the firefox debug console

```
Use of getUserData() or setUserData() is deprecated.  Use WeakMap or element.dataset instead. requestNotifier.js:64
"Opening Web Socket..." stomp.js:130
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://127.0.0.5:8888/hello. wsTest:18
"Whoops! Lost connection to wss://127.0.0.5:8888/hello" stomp.js:130
```

here is full version of the html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello WebSocket</title>
    <script src="/js/stomp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var stompClient = null;

        function setConnected(connected) {
            document.getElementById('connect').disabled = connected;
            document.getElementById('disconnect').disabled = !connected;
            document.getElementById('conversationDiv').style.visibility = connected ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
            document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = '';
        }

        function connect() {
            var socket = new WebSocket("wss://127.0.0.5:8888/hello");

            stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
 //           stompClient.connect('tito', 'password', function(frame) {
            stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
                setConnected(true);
                console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
                stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function(greeting){
                    showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
                });
            });
        }

        function disconnect() {
            stompClient.disconnect();
            setConnected(false);
            console.log("Disconnected");
        }

        function sendName() {
            var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            stompClient.send("/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify({ 'name': name }));
        }

        function showGreeting(message) {
            var response = document.getElementById('response');
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            p.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
            p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
            response.appendChild(p);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript><h2 style="color: #ff0000">Seems your browser doesn't support Javascript! Websocket relies on Javascript being enabled. Please enable
    Javascript and reload this page!</h2></noscript>
<div>
    <div>
        <button id="connect" onclick="connect();">Connect</button>
        <button id="disconnect" disabled="disabled" onclick="disconnect();">Disconnect</button>
    </div>
    <div id="conversationDiv">
        <label>What is your name?</label><input type="text" id="name" />
        <button id="sendName" onclick="sendName();">Send</button>
        <p id="response"></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the stomp script version used is "// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.3"

here is how the certificate was generated

```
$ keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA  -keystore /home/tito/Projects/syncServer/Server/certificate/sync.keystore
Enter keystore password:  
Re-enter new password: 
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  TestFirstName
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]:  TestOrganizationalUnitName
What is the name of your organization?
  [Unknown]:  TestOrganization
What is the name of your City or Locality?
  [Unknown]:  TestCity
What is the name of your State or Province?
  [Unknown]:  TestState
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
  [Unknown]:  BG
Is CN=TestFirstName, OU=TestOrganizationalUnitName, O=TestOrganization, L=TestCity, ST=TestState, C=BG correct?
  [no]:  yes

Enter key password for <tomcat>
        (RETURN if same as keystore password):
```

Addition: I have also noticed that web sockets are working if i call

```
https://127.0.0.5:8888/wsTest
```

but not working if I call

```
https://localhost:8888/wsTest
```

however i still have not found why is this happening. This behavior is the same with chrome and firefox.

Comment: You definitely need an HTTPS connector for Websockets with SSL (I.e. your "wss://*" client). It's possible it isn't working because of the certificate problem (you accepted the risk for direct browser connections, but maybe you have to do something similar for the JavaScript client, like set a flag on it). I don't really know the client side of it very well.

Comment: Hello Dave, thank you for the quick response, I know that i need the https connector for wss to work however my question was do i need to have the http also simultaneously with the https connector. What relates to the client side, this is the standard page executed from the web browser taken from the spring guides i.e.  https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-stomp-websocket/blob/master/complete/src/main/resources/static/index.html. I have only changed the part that is customer for mozilla i.e. creating the web socket :  var socket = new WebSocket("wss://127.0.0.5:8888/hello");

Comment: and removed the sockjs lib as i do not any fallback i.e. removed  <script src="sockjs-0.3.4.js"></script>

Comment: No, you don't need HTTP as well. Do you see any errors or messages in the browser console (developer tools)?

Comment: yes i do , i added those messaged to the end of the problem description

Comment: Can you see the security exception on the right port and host in Firefox config?

Comment: Dave, I am not sure i am following, can you please rephrase that last sentence. Do you mean i need to go in the firefox config i.e. "about:config" and search something there ? Or do you mean if the port is correct i.e. 8888 if so then yes, it is.

Comment: How about just trying it in Chrome?

Comment: In firefox you'd have to go to options - advanced - encryption, then hit the "View Certificates" button and look at the Servers. Make sure that the hostname and port you need are there.

Comment: Hello Dave, thank you for the support. It does work now. I am not sure why but here is what i did. I have generated a new certificate , with the same command that i used before. Then i saw that my last certificate had in all of the field only one character values. Maybe that was the problem from the beginning. When i put some really meaningful data into the certificate it worked for bought chrome and firefox.

Comment: Hello @Tito, I am implementing the same scenario as you mentioned above, but still, I am facing some issue, could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need an HTTPS connector for Websockets with SSL (I.e. your "wss://*" client). It's possible it isn't working because of the certificate problem. If I were you I'd double check the browser configuration for the certificate exceptions. Maybe regenerate the certificate and try again.

Comment: Hello Dave can you elaborate on how to check  the browser configuration for the certificate exceptions? for example for firefox?

Comment: Yes, look at my comment on your question.

Comment: ok I got it you mean "to go to options - advanced - encryption, then hit the "View Certificates" button and look at the Servers" I first thought that is a exception like in java try catch block but it seems i need to work on my english :)